# Approximating $\int_2^4 e^{\frac{1}{x}} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, approximation

> Estimate the integral precisely up to the error of $0.001$:$$\int_2^4 e^{\frac{1}{x}} dx$$

I started by dividing the segment $[2,4]$ into some pieces $(n=5)$ as in the following figure:

$\qquad\qquad\quad$[image]

---

Now, I have $$\Delta x = \frac{4-2}{5} = 0.4$$ and therefore, $$S \approx \sum_{i=1}^5 f(x_i)(x_i - x_{i-1}) = \Delta x \sum_{i=1}^5 e^{\frac{1}{x_i}}$$ where $x_i = 2 + 0.4i$.

Then, approximating the area boils down to approximating the exponential function at $5$ points. What is the best way to proceed? And how do I know that the final result will give the error at most $0.001$?

Comment: @Moo I was familiar with the rectangle method, but surfing the net also got familiar with trapezium and Simpson's rule. However, the rectangle method is still preferred in my case.

Comment: @Moo I think I meant the Midpoint rule by Rectangular (don't know the right phrase). But any method is welcome for sure, I'm ready to learn new stuff from the answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Midpoint Rule error is given by

$$\tag 1 |E_n| \le \left|\dfrac{(b-a)^3}{24 n^2}\right | |\max_{2 \le x \le 4}f''(x^*)|$$

The second derivative of $f(x) = e^{1/x}$ is

$$f''(x)= \dfrac{e^{1/x} (2 x + 1)}{x^4}$$

So, we want to find the max of $|f''(x)|$ over the interval $[2,4]$

$$\displaystyle \max_{2 \le x \le 4}\left| \dfrac{e^{1/x} (2 x + 1)}{x^4}\right| = \dfrac{5 \sqrt{e}}{16} ~ \mbox{at}~ x = 2$$

Substituting everything we have into $(1)$

$$|E_n| \le \dfrac{(4-2)^3}{24 n^2} \left(\dfrac{5 \sqrt{e}}{16}\right) \le 0.001$$

Can you continue by solving that for $n$? You should find

$$n \ge 13.105$$

We would choose an integer at $n = 14$.

Note that that is an upper bound and can be way off.

In practice, using trial and error gives eight intervals for an absolute error $< 0.001$

$$2.83456$$

Using [*WA*](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5E%281%2Fx%29+from+x+%3D+2+to+4), the closed form is ugly, and the numerical result is

$$\displaystyle \int_2^4 e^{1/x} dx \approx 2.835422294875796952$$

**Update** If you want to see the intermediate Midpoint Rule steps above, use this [*calculator*](https://www.emathhelp.net/calculators/calculus-2/midpoint-rule-calculator/?f=e%5E%281%2Fx%29&a=2&b=4&n=8&steps=on).

Comment: Thank you, this is going to help.  But after finding the value of $n$ so that the error is in the right range, should $e^\frac{1}{x_i}$ be approximated at each of those $n$ points?

Comment: Ok, how did you calculate $2.83456$? I was wondering if there was a way to do all the approximations by hand...

Comment: Thank you for the link and effort. What do you think: does the problem ask to approximate the powers of $e$ in the end, too, or are they allowed to be calculated via calculator. Actually, the statement says nothing about this point.

Comment: I am not sure based on how the question is written. The closed form result for that integral is nasty and a numerical solver was required to find the actual result to compare against. The first method is using a gross approximation that typically over approximates how many intervals you need. Where is this problem from and what is being studied - that should help clarify matters as I'd be guessing what someone intended.

Answer (score 1):

$$\exp(1/x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{-n}}{n!}$$
$$\int\exp(1/x)dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{1-n}}{(1-n)n!}+C$$
then sub in your limits and take a few terms, so thats one option

---

$$\int_2^4e^{1/x}dx=\int_{1/4}^{1/2}\frac{e^u}{u^2}du=\int_{1/4}^{1/2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{u^{n-2}}{n!}du$$
so you have two choices here

Comment: The first one is wrong. There Will be a 1/x term which when integrated gives a ln(x) term.

Comment: @Simon yep but the bounds are domain is $[2,4]$ so it doesn't cause a problem

Comment: I’m talking about the series on the right hand side. When n=1, You’re dividing by zero and the term should be ln x.

Comment: @Simon ah yes you are correct